# Anonymous class do not have an argument

Tags: java

I am learning Apache Spark. Given such an implementation of spark using java below, I am confused about some details about it.

```
public class JavaWordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: JavaWordCount <master> <file>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(args[0], "JavaWordCount",
        System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), System.getenv("SPARK_EXAMPLES_JAR"));
    JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile(args[1], 1);

    JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
      public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
        return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
      }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.map(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
      }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
      public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return i1 + i2;
      }
    });

    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> output = counts.collect();
    for (Tuple2 tuple : output) {
      System.out.println(tuple._1 + ": " + tuple._2);
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

According to my comprehension, begin in line 12, it passed an anonymous class `FlatMapFunction` into the `lines.flatMap()` as an argument. Then what does the `String s` mean? It seems that it doesn't pass an created `String s` as an argument, then how will the `FlatMapFunction<String,String>(){}` class works since no specific arguments are passed into?

Comment: `String s` is an argument for `call` method in that anonymous class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anonymous class instance you're passing is overriding the `call(String s)` method. Whatever is receiving this anonymous class instance is something that wants to make use of that `call()` method during its execution: it will be (somehow) constructing strings and passing them (directly or indirectly) to the `call()` method of whatever you've passed in.

So the fact that *you're* not invoking the method you've defined isn't a worry: something else is doing so.

This is a common use case for anonymous inner classes. A method `m()` expects to be passed something that implements the `Blah` interface, and the `Blah` interface has a `frobnicate(String s)` method in it. So we call it with

```
m(new Blah() {
    public void frobnicate(String s) {
        //exciting code goes here to do something with s
    }
});
```

and the `m` method will now be able to take this instance that implements `Blah`, and invoke `frobnicate()` on it.

Perhaps `m` looks like this:

```
public void m(Blah b) {
    b.frobnicate("whatever");
}
```

Now the `frobnicate()` method that we wrote in our inner class is being invoked, and as it runs, the parameter `s` will be set to `"whatever"`.

Comment: But according to the codes in my question, I didn't see anything that calls that method. This is weird, because it is complete example realizing the function of `word count`.

Comment: @Liquid that's because it's inside the definition of `.flatMap()` that it will be invoking that method. It's inside code you haven't shown and don't normally need to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

All your are doing here is passing a FlatMapFunction as argument to the flatMap method; your passed FlatMapFunction overrides call(String s):

```
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() 
{
  public Iterable<String> call(String s)
  {
    return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
  }
});
```

The code implementing lines.flatMap could look like this for instance:

```
public JavaRDD<String> flatMap(FlatMapFunction<String, String> map)
{
    String str = "some string";
    Iterable<String> it = map.call(str);
    // do stuff with 'it'
    // return a JavaRDD<String>
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that a `String` maybe already pre-defined in the class?

Comment: What do you mean with "pre-defined"? If you mean a constant literal, such as in my example, I cannot say for sure. The actual implementation would use 'some' value it has determined to use beforehand - this maybe a literal or a value retrieved from another collection, a database, etc. The value retrieved could potentially come from anywhere. I suggest you look into the actual implementation of the flatMap method. If you have trouble figuring what that code does, just ask another question, comment the link here, and I will be sure to check it out as well :)